# Deduping an array of objects with similar datetimes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, datetime, lodash

I am trying to dedupe an array of JSON objects where the content and author are the same, but the timestamp is slightly different (i.e. within 1 second).  I'd like to preserve the duplicated messages as a new field, called duplicates.  For example, consider the following which has as entries 2,3 and 5 messages which should be deduped :

```
myObject = [
{content: 'content1', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:40.000', author: 'Person1'}, 
{content: 'content2', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:40.900', author: 'Person2'},
{content: 'content2', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:41.100', author: 'Person2'},
{content: 'content3', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:41.000', author: 'Person1'},
{content: 'content2', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:41.400', author: 'Person2'},
{content: 'content4', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:45.100', author: 'Person2'},
]
```

should be transformed to :

```
deduped = [
{content: 'content1', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:40.000', author: 'Person1', duplicates: 0}, 
{content: 'content2', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:40.900', author: 'Person2', duplicates: 2},
{content: 'content3', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:41.000', author: 'Person1', duplicates: 0},
{content: 'content4', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:45.100', author: 'Person2', duplicates: 0},
]
```

The part that I am having trouble with is the datetime.  Sorting by datetime and then reducing is prone to errors if a non duplicate message occurs between the duplicates.  And comparing the string value of the datetimes is also error prone because two messages may be very close together, but show as 1 second apart based on where they fall.

Using lodash _.uniqWith, I can dedupe based on the combination of a actual timedelta with identical content and author, but I lack the duplicates field...

```
const dedupedButNoCount = _.uniqWith(myObject, (item1, item2) => 
{return (item1.content== item2.content) && (item1.author== item2.author) 
&& ((new Date(item1.date).getTime() - new Date(item2.date).getTime())<500)}
)
```

Any pointers on how to dedupe an array of objects with similar but not identical datetimes?

Comment: I'm too busy today to type out a full answer, but you could always use Array.filter() and Array.Reduce() to extract any other elements in the array that are within N seconds. It's not a simple solution, but I think you weren't expecting simple when you wrote the question.

Comment: two questions: 1-the beginning of this algorithm will certainly impose a sorting: is it necessary to preserve the original order?
2-when you write 1 second apart: in the case of 3 elements following each other at 900ms between them, the first and the last have more than a second apart, should they be ungrouped?

Comment: Thanks for the idea Graham.  And for clarification Jojo, the original order is sorted by timestamp, and it is not necessary to preserve that order as I'm still able to sort if need be at the end.  For part 2, I think it would be reasonable to consider the time delta from the first message.  So for three messages which are each 900ms apart, the second would be considered a duplicate of the first, but the third would be considered to be a new message.  In order to dedupe all three, would just require that the timedelta be set large enough to capture all 3 (in the case you mentioned, 2 seconds).

Comment: The 900ms doesn't make sense because if a=b and b=c then a=c

Comment: Personally, I find that your 2 answers really complicate the work, because it implies that you have to search for the first identical previous elements for each entry, and if they have less than 1 second to search in the result on which line you have to increment the number of duplicates...

Comment: Would you propose a different criterion on which to identify duplicates?  I'm open to suggestions and interested in framing the problem in the simplest most efficient way.

Comment: The below suggested approach works great.  Thanks Mister Jojo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done that, but I use a sort...

```js
const
  getTimeMs = YMDhmsx =>     // date string conversion to UTC (time zone = 0)
    {
    let [Y,M,D,h,m,s,x] = YMDhmsx.split(/\-|\.|\s|\:/).map(Number)
    return (new Date(Date.UTC(Y,--M,D,h,m,s,x))).getTime() // time UTC value in ms
    }
, myObject = [
    {content: 'content1', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:40.000', author: 'Person1'}, 
    {content: 'content2', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:40.900', author: 'Person2'},
    {content: 'content2', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:41.100', author: 'Person2'},
    {content: 'content3', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:41.000', author: 'Person1'},
    {content: 'content2', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:41.400', author: 'Person2'},
    {content: 'content4', date: '1980-08-01 12:12:45.100', author: 'Person2'},
    ]
    
let result = 
  myObject
  .sort( (a,b) =>
    a.content.localeCompare(b.content) || 
    a.author.localeCompare(b.author) || 
    a.date.localeCompare(b.date) 
    )
  .reduce( (r,el,i,{[i-1]:prev}) =>
    {
    let msTime = getTimeMs(el.date)

    if (el.content === prev?.content 
     && el.author === prev?.author
     && (msTime - r.msTime) <= 1000 )  // 1 second less on previous
      r.current.duplicates++;
    else
      {
      r.current = {...el, duplicates:0 }
      r.result.push( r.current )
      }
    r.msTime = msTime
    return r
    }
    , {msTime:0, current:null, result:[] })
  .result;
  
console.log ( 'result:\n' + JSON.stringify( result ).replaceAll('},{','}\n,{') )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```